# PHP CURL issue with an API when retrieving datas

Tags: php, api, curl, postman

we have an API existing with a distributor.
Our software is running under PHP 7.3.6 / Apache 2.4.38
We already successfully did some other actions: creating new purchase orders, retrieving orders, ...
We have a problem to retrieve invoices.
We are using for our API tests a software called POSTMAN.
We input all the informations (api key, ....)
Using POSTMAN, it works perfectly.  There is an option in POSTMAN to obtain the code in different langage. For our needs, we took the PHP generated code. The problem is that it is not working.
We also used https://reqbin.com/curl and it works perfectly. But same problem, the generated code in PHP is not working.

For example, in postman or reqbin, this CURL code is working

```
curl -X GET https://url.com/Invoices?startDate="01-01-2019"&endDate="01-31-2023" \
-H 'Accept: application/json' \
-H 'Authorization: Bearer generatedtokenzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'zzzzzzzzz-API-Key: generatedapikeyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'
```

when we click on generate PHP code we have this code:

```
<?php

$url = "https://url.com/Invoices?startDate="01-01-2019"&endDate="01-31-2023";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Authorization: Bearer generatedtokenzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "zzzzzzzzz-API-Key: generatedapikeyzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);

?>
```

Because it didn't work , we tried to add some options like

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
```

and it still don't work.

We are getting crazy, we are on this problem for more than a week....

Any help would be very usefull.

Many thanks by advance....

Comment: Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. The problem with your question is that "doesn't work" is not a suitable error description. Another problem with above PHP code becomes obvious once you enable syntax highlighting in your editor and pay attention to fine details, but it's also visible above.

Comment: The message we have is:  {"message": "list index out of range"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We find the bug.
it was not in the part of this code but it was above.
a parameter was not passed correctly, and the error message {message": "list index out of range} was in fact wrong.